# What is the computational complexity of generating a stream from a hashset in java? We may consider a hashset with $n$ elements and $m$ capacity

Tags: java, stream, complexity-theory, hashset

What is the computational complexity of generating a stream from a hashset in java?  We may consider a hashset with $n$ elements and $m$ capacity.

For example:

```
Hashset hashset = new HashSet(m);
// ... put n < m elements in the hashset ...
hashset.stream().do something;
```

I'm not interested in the complexity of do something, just the complexity of building the stream.

Answer (score 4):

Creating the stream is `O(1)`, it's just the creation of the pipeline structure.

Then, a terminal operation *pulls* elements from the source (in this case, the hash set) and intermediate operations (if any) are applied.

Creating a stream is *declarative* i.e. nothing happens with elements, until a terminal operation is invoked.